# how to make a list of phone numbers to call in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a list of  titles but not attached the numbers to be given according to the titles.
I want to give the numbers and made call on them according to the user will call on select.
I am making a emergency number app and want to give the numbers with the titles in app, when the user will select a number according to need he will call ..
please guide me
This is my code:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button EmergencyBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        EmergencyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmergencyContacts.class);
                startActivity(emerIntent);

            }
        });
```

EmergencyContacts.class

```
public class EmergencyContacts extends ListActivity {


    static final String[] EmergencyNumbers = new String[]{
            "Ambulance","Hilal-e-Ahmar","Edhi Trust","Bomb Disposal","Board of Secondary Education",
            "Chambers of Commerce & Industry","Civil Defence","Civil Secretariat","Export Promotion ",
            "Bureau","Fatmid Blood ","Transfusion ","Fire Brigade Center","General post office(GPO)",
            "Govt. transport(GTS)","Hospital Civil(casualties)","Hospital services (Casualties)",
            "Income Tax","Metropolitan corp.","News Agency(APP)","Police Emergency","Railway Station (City)",
            "PIA Flight Enquiry","PIA Reservation","PIA Cargo","Passport Office","PTV ","Pakistan Tourism Dev. Corp.",
            "PAF (Recrut)","Pakistan Army (Recruiting)","Pakistan Navy (Recruiting)","Radio Pakistan","Railway Enquiry",
            "Railway Reservation (Cantt.)","Railway Reservation (city)","Sui Gas Complaints","Time Enquiry",
            "Telephone Enquiry","Telephone Complaints","Trunk Overseas ","Booking","Trunk inland Enquiry","Phonogram",
            "Overseas Booking","Overseas Enquiry","Telegraph Enquiry","Text Book Board","University","University Allama Iqbal",
            "University of Engin and Tech","Weather (Enq)","Wapda (Enq)","PAKISTAN TOURISM DEV. CORP","PAKISTAN ARMY (RECRUITING)",
             "PAKISTAN NAVY (RECRUITING)"


    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,EmergencyNumbers));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }



    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,int position,long id){

        //TODO Auto generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);




        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Call to?"+"\n"+getListView().getItemAtPosition(position))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       // EmergencyContacts.this.finish();


                         Intent callTo = new Intent(EmergencyContacts.this,CallTo.class);
                        startActivity(callTo);

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


}
```

callTo.class

```
public class CallTo extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_to);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_to);
       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String number =  getString(R.string.phone_number);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Call client :"));

    }
 });
}
```

Happy to help

Comment: Sir i will not give numbers like this but in a list and then it will be selected by user according to the title clicked

Comment: thanks dear you are making me more clear and more closer but i have a question that how to get a string of phone_number according to the list_item clicked and where i give strings for the each list item so that they are linked to them please

Comment: Have you created arraylist of all phone number?

Comment: no but i tried this ok i m creating an array of phone numbers then i will ask you question how to connect them stay on friend


HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashmap.Entry("Ambulance",1212)

Comment: dear i i have share all of my code above but the new one is this

HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashmap.put("Ambulance",1212)
    hashmap.put("Second item", 100);
    hashmap.put("Third item", 200);


first of all its giving error in .put and i dont know how to utilize this

Comment: I have been waiting for you sir:-)

Comment: 1. Put all your data into ArrayList. 2. Set that list to listView using Adapter. 3. Create onClickLis of convertView in Adapter. 4. Here you get phone number by clicking on row of list

Comment: Sir can you please see here i am stucked here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283395/how-to-call-on-item-selected-of-listview

Comment: Your Emergency Numbers size is greater than hot lines. Make them equal